# Adding a document to a collections keeps hanging

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-thunk

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to React Native and Firebase in general, so this might be me just being dumb. Anyways, I'm trying to learn something new and making a test app at the same time and I've run into an issue when registering users.

I have an action that I dispatch that should be able to Authenticate users and at the same time add the user.uid and email to a collection called users.

The problem is that every time that I call the await to add the user the app just hangs there and nothing happens. I tried to resolve the Promise or catch an error and it still gives me nothing.

Here's the full action:

```
export const registerUser =
    (
        email: string,
        password: string,
    ): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, SignUpTypes> =>
    async (dispatch: Dispatch<SignUpTypes>) => {
        dispatch({ type: SIGN_UP });

        try {
            const response = await firebase
                .auth()
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

            const { user, additionalUserInfo } = response;

            const userProfile = {
                uid: user?.uid,
                email,
            };

            await usersCollection
                .doc(user?.uid)
                .set(userProfile)
                .then(res => console.log('res', res))
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

            dispatch({
                type: SIGN_UP_COMPLETE,
                payload: {
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                    user: userProfile,
                    isNewUser: additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: SIGN_UP_ERROR,
                payload: { error: { code: error.code, message: error.message } },
            });
        }
    };
```

I got nothing from the moment that I call the await on the usersCollection, not even a console log and everything just freezes there. Not sure if it's something related to thunks but or not.

Also, it if helps I'm always having this warning:

```
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info
```

Any ideas on what am I missing?

Thanks ✌

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine `await` and `then`. To get your logs try this:

```js
try {
const res = await usersCollection
                .doc(user?.uid)
                .set(userProfile)
console.log('res', res)
}
catch(e){
console.log('e', e)
}
```

Comment: I only added the then and catch to make a point, forgot to remove the await.
Regardless, even with you try, it still hangs, and when it does not hang it simply ignores it, dispatches the complete action but does no add anything to the collection. No console logs either